# Updating CSS using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, styling

I am new to AngularJS and I would like to learn the best way to do this.

Here's my issue:
I have an anchor, that - after clicking on it - should toggle between classes "show-all" and "hide-all", and also update the css of a div.

Here's what i have so far:

```
<a class="{{state}}" href="#" ng-click="ToggleDisplay()"><p>{{stateTitle}}</p></a>
<div>CSS should be updated here</div>
```

And a bonus question: is there and easy way to transition the CSS change on the div (which is from height:200px to height:auto)?

Comment: dimensions can't be animated (transitioned) in CSS if they have the start or end point 'auto', but it can be hacked by defining i.e. start: `max-height:200px` and end: `max-height: 1000px` - the only problem with this is that the transition time is always calculated from precise values, so if the content is of height 500px, the animation of height will be finished quicker than if the content is 900px

Comment: and css updating is done this way `<div ng-style="{'max-height': state=='show-all' ? '1000px' : '200px'}">whatever</div>` http://jsfiddle.net/tQ9Af/

Comment: Thanks, it worked! :) Although i decided not to use the transition, as the height of the divs varies a lot, and the closing transition of short divs looks a bit funny when the max-height is set to 1000px.

Answer (score 0):

to do a show all, hide all methods  you can use the ng-show or the ng-hide methods, binding a keyword in it, you can make a method to use with the anchor to solve you're problem like that way

HTML

```
<a ng-click="showAll()">show all</a>
<p ng-show="hide">things to hide</p>
<p ng-show="hide">other things to hide</p>
```

JS

```
$scope.showAll=function(){
    if($scope.hide==false){
        $scope.hide=true;
    }else{
        $scope.hide=false
    }
 }
```

Another great way is the ng-class method where you can put a style code and make it a variable to change in your js file.

EDIT
a sample for ng-class:

```
<div ng-class="heightsample">i'm a div 100px's height</div>
<button ng-click="height-change()">change</button>
```

JS

```
$scope.heightsample={height:'100px'}
$scope.height-change=function(){
    $scope.heightsample={height:'50px'}

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i don't want to hide the divs, i just want to limit their height, so ng-show doesn't work in my case. The ng-class method is more likely, and by writing this question I was hoping to see good examples of how to use it.